# C# How to Get Output from CMD (Command = "Defrag c: /U") Before Proccess Ends.

Tags: c#, cmd, output

I'm calling Defrag.exe from my c# application. I want to get output of defragmentation proccess when it's updated.

I want this output(in red rectangle) to be printed in my application.(When 11% progress percentage updated it should also be printed.) :

[image]

I'm using this code:

```
Process selectedProc = new Process();
selectedProc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
selectedProc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
selectedProc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
selectedProc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

selectedProc.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => 
{                
       Debug.WriteLine(e.Data); 
};

selectedProc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory);
selectedProc.StartInfo.FileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "defrag.exe");
selectedProc.StartInfo.Arguments = "C: /U";
selectedProc.Start();
selectedProc.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

After sometime i'm closing process with this code:

```
selectedProc.Kill();
```

Between process.Start() and process.Kill() i'm not seeing any output printed on debug section in Visual Studio. Not even after defrag process ended. Where is the problem ?

Comment: It might be on the Error stream...

Comment: No, it also does not output anything on Error stream.

Comment: too bad. And why don't you use the WMI provider instead? http://stackoverflow.com/a/11873832/578411

Comment: Didn't understand if that answer related with my question. DefragAnalysis analyzes volume and tells if defragmentation is required or not. I want to track progress while i'm defragmenting drive.(As you can see in the screenshot)

Comment: It invokes Defrag, defraganalysis is the output parameter...

Comment: But i want to see the progress, the WMI doesn't provide any mechanism to monitor the progress of the defrag method.

Comment: When I run a `defrag e: /U > d:\defrag.txt` I get the whole sequence of progress lines in the file. Do you, too?

Comment: Yes, but defrag.txt filled when the defrag proccess ended.

Comment: From what I've read, I'm gathering that when stdout is sent to defrag.txt, it appears in that file after the process has completed, yet when the Process.OutputDataReceived is used in C#, no data appears during execution.  Two thoughts: (1) When using Process.OutputDataReceived, perhaps defrag does not call flush() on a regular basis, so the data isn't written to a stream on a regular basis.  (2) If you're seeing output in defrag.txt, while defrag is running, maybe you can use a FileSystemWatcher to read defrag.txt whenever it's updated.

Comment: Did you try something like [this](https://github.com/MortenHoustonLudvigsen/ProcessRunner)?

Comment: @galenus Same results.. No output received :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to run cmd as administrator and pass arguments to run defragmentation

```
namespace System.IO.Defrag
{
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    public class Defrag
    {
        private Process ownprocess;
public void Stop()
        {
            ownprocess?.Kill();
        }
        private IDictionary<Operations, string> vOperations = new Dictionary<Operations, string>()
        {
            {Operations.Analyze, "/A "},{ Operations.BootOptimize,"/B "},{ Operations.Defrag ,"/D "},
            {Operations.Optimize ,"/O "},{ Operations.FreespaceConsolidate,"/X "},{ Operations.PrintProgress,"/U "},
            {Operations.Retrim,"/L " },{ Operations.SlabConsolidate ,"/K "},{ Operations.TierOptimize,"/G "},
            {Operations.TrackProgress ,"/T "},{ Operations.Verbose,"/V"}
        };
        private IDictionary<Options, string> vOptions = new Dictionary<Options, string>()
        {
            {Options.MultiThread , "/M" },{ Options.MaxRuntime, "I"},{ Options.NormalPriority , "/H"},
            { Options.None,""}
        };
        public enum Options
        {
            NormalPriority,
            MaxRuntime,
            MultiThread,
            None
        }
        public enum Operations
        {
            Analyze,
            BootOptimize,
            Defrag,
            TierOptimize,
            SlabConsolidate,
            Retrim,
            Optimize,
            TrackProgress,
            PrintProgress,
            Verbose,
            FreespaceConsolidate
        }
        private string English = "437";
        public event DataReceivedEventHandler OutputData;

        public T GetValue<T>(string data)
        {
            object o = new object();
            T a = (T)o;
            if (a is string)
            {
                Regex he = new Regex(": (.*?)% ");
                var j = he.Match(data);
                o = j.Groups[1].Value;
                a = (T)o;
            }
            else if (a is int)
            {
                Regex he = new Regex(": (.*?)% ");
                var j = he.Match(data);
                o = Convert.ToInt32(j.Groups[1].Value);
                a = (T)o;
            }
            else if (a is double)
            {
                Regex he = new Regex(": (.*?)% ");
                var j = he.Match(data);
                o = Convert.ToDouble(j.Groups[1].Value);
                a = (T)o;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This format is not supported.",$"Error 0x{Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(a.GetType().Name).Length}",MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }
            return a;
        }
        private void cmd(string arg)
        {

            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd",$"/c start \"\" chcp {English} && start \"\" {arg}");
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

            if (OutputData != null)
            {
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.OutputDataReceived += OutputData;
                ownprocess = process;
                process.Start();
                process.BeginOutputReadLine();
            }else
            {
                ownprocess = process;
                process.Start();

            }
        }
        public async void Start(string Volumes = "C:", Operations dOparations  = Operations.Defrag, Options options = Options.None)
        {
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
            {
                cmd($"defrag {Volumes} {vOperations[dOparations]}{vOptions[options]}");

            });
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: if you just run defrag you will not see the output

Comment: Given how long the code sample is, it would be useful to call out the relevant features.